# Dtrace Invalid Probe Specifier error

Tags: linux, debugging, ubuntu, dtrace

I installed Dtrace in Ubuntu 11.04.

I was able to run:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall:::'
```

and:

```
sudo dtrace -l | grep terminal
```

commands properly and got the results.

But when I tried to run:

```
dtrace -n 'proc:::exec-success { trace(curpsinfo->pr_psargs); }'
```

I'm getting error saying:

> `dtrace`: invalid probe specifier `proc:::exec-success` { trace(curpsinfo->pr_psargs); }: probe description `proc:::exec-success` does not match any probes.

What is wrong here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Check `dtrace -l` to see that the `proc:::exec-success` probe exists. DTrace ports take on different providers at different times. An incomplete port might not yet have the proc provider.

Comment: Okay, mine doesn't exist. Now what? How do I fix that?

Comment: nm - found the answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208185/6907 Basically, Apple disabled some parts of dtrace with El Capitan.

Comment: You'll need to check with the port maintainer. Nothing much you can do yourself. You could however figure out a kernel function that corresponds to the same event and see if the fbt provider is working.